# Native Javascript HTML5 Progress bar slow loading/animation

Tags: javascript, html

I have created progress bar using HTML5 like below.

```
<progress id="prog" max="100" value="0" > </progress> <br/>
```

and for animations I am using CSS and Javascript. For some reason I don't want to use external JS libraries. I have done most of it, only issue is that when I set value of progress using JS, it updates quickly which is obvious why. But I want it to appear slow slow and make some delay so for example on some button press value goes from 0% to 20% so I want to use some function/mechanism so progress bar updates slowly.

Comment: Use `requestAnimationFrame()` or CSS transitions.

Comment: You can just make the progress bar wider which will cause it to fill up more slowly.